# increase memory size elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Just wondering, where/how do I run:

```
ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms16G -Xmx16G" ./bin/elasticsearch
```

to increase the memory please? I tried to put this into the startup batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to modify the first section of the `config/jvm.options` file

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms16g
-Xmx16g
```